# body.req is splitted to multiple logs

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, webhooks

I have a js project running with GCP app engine and I'm facing an issue with a `req.body` of a webhook request.

I'm viewing the logs using the `gcloud app logs tail -s` command.
I got the following result for `console.log(req.body)`:

```
2021-03-28 13:36:06 default[20210328t132629]  {

2021-03-28 13:36:06 default[20210328t132629]    '{"key1":"someData" ,"key2":{"key2.1":"someData","key2.2":"someData,"key2.3":"someData","key2.4":"someData,.................,"key2.500":"someData"}, "key3": { 'key3.1': [ '1616991667' ] },

2021-03-28 13:36:06 default[20210328t132629]    'Key4': 'somwData',

2021-03-28 13:36:06 default[20210328t132629]    Signauture: 'someData_"},somwKey":null}}}'

2021-03-28 13:36:06 default[20210328t132629]  }
```

As shown, `req.body` is splitted to multiple logs, why does it happen? how can I avoid it?

Comment: I guess this is because you have some line breaks in `req.body`. Try to remove linebreaks before printing it.

Comment: maybe i'm doing it wrong... but i tried:

let a = ("" + data).replace('\n', '')
console.log(a) 

it didn't solve it :(

Answer (score 0):

Most of the GCP service like GKE, Compute engine and App engine uses **fluentd** which exports the logs in string format by default. If the log entry is long, it splits it into multiple lines.

The solution to format the log properly in JSON is to use libraries like [winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) and [bunyan](https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan)

[Source](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/nodejs)